# I have a class as instance of another class, is there a way I can isolate which the first class is?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, abstract-class

Sorry if the question is worded strangely, I'm relatively new to python and coding in general.

I have a Parent class with an abstract method like so:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Parent(ABC):
    def __init__(self,input):
        self.input = input

    @abstractmethod
    def abcmethod(self): pass

class Child_1(Parent):
    def abcmethod(self):
        return self.input + 1

class Child_2(Parent):
    def abcmethod(self):
        return self.input + 2

class Foo:
    def __init__(self,input, child):
        self.input = input
        self.child = child
    
    def method(self):
        x = self.child(self.input)
        return x

tester = Foo(4, Child_1)
```

So here I have the Parent class and two child classes with the shared abstract method of abcmethod(). Then I have another class Foo which whose instance is one of the child classes.

I need to isolate which child class was used in the Foo class, i.e. Child_1 or Child_2. I tried tester.**dict**.values() but it came up with the object, how can I use this in say an if statement?

```
tester.__dict__.values()
>>> <class '__main__.Child_1'>

#Something like...
for i in tester.__dict__.values():
    if i is Child_1:
        \\ do this
    elif i is Child_2:
        \\ do something else
```

Sorry it's long-winded. Any help with this issue would be so appreciated!

Comment: 1. You can use `type`. 2. Why do you care? You already implemented `abcmethod` in both classes. So just call `abcmethod` and it will behave correctly. 3. This seems like a bad design. Why would an outside code (the code that uses `tester`) care how `tester` was initialized? it's very unmaintainable.  All this logic should be performed inside `Foo` class

Comment: `issubclass(tester.child, Child_1)`…? `tester.child is Child_1`? But this rather goes against the idea of OOP. Objects should define *behaviour* and you invoke that behaviour without caring about what type of object exactly you're dealing with. What are you trying to figure out here?

Comment: @DeepSpace I only started coding 6 months ago so this is all very new. The idea in my head is that I want to implement another function to make different actions depending on which Child class is used in the Foo class. Are you saying I should put this action I want to complete within the Foo class as apose to outside?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what abstract methods are for. You define an *interface*, i.e. "`Foo` requires an object that implements a method `abcmethod`", then `Foo` calls `.abcmethod()` on whatever object is being passed to it. Now you can subclass `Parent` into as many different children as you like, each with their individual behaviour for `abcmethod`, without needing to do any special implementation anywhere else in your code (i.e. no other part of your code needs to know what children might exist and do something different based on that).

Comment: @CharlieVagg `"Are you saying I should put this action I want to complete within the Foo class as apose to outside?"` Yes. Imagine that you have a very large application that creates, let's say, 100 instances of `Foo`, in multiple places. Will you copy-paste that logic 100 different times? Will you remember to change it in 100 places if the logic changes?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not put this capability in your *Child* subclasses itself?:

```py
class Child_1(Parent):
    def abcmethod(self):
        return self.input + 1
    def do(self):
        print("do this")

class Child_2(Parent):
    def abcmethod(self):
        return self.input + 2
    def do(self):
        print("do something else")
```

Now, once you have your `tester` object you can just call `tester.child.do()`